# For what value of C is P(X=n) = C/n! For all n in the non-negative integers a probability density function?

Tags: probability

For what value of $C$ is $P(X=n) = \frac{C}{n!}$? For all n in the non-negative integers a probability density function?

Summary of what I did:

Set $f(n)$ equal to $1$ and summed over all non negative integers.

Used $\frac1{n!}$ as defined by the recurrence relation $a(n)=\frac{a(n-1)}{(n+1)}$. With initial conditions $a_0=1,a_1=1$.

$C(1/0!$ + $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$

Then used infinite version of geometric series formula.

$C(1+(1*(1/2))/(1-1/2))$

$C=1/2.$

Comment: This will be Poisson distribution with parameter $1$. Answer is $C = e^{-1}$

Comment: In general we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$

Comment: "*Then used infinite version of geometric series formula...*"  That should only be used for geometric series, as the name implies.  This is not a geometric series.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$

So, by plugging in $1$ in place of $x$ we have:

$$e = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$$

Dividing both sides by $e$ gives us

$$1 = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-1}}{n!}$$